# ERROR - Cannot stat file /proc/32641/fd/338 - Qual utilidade do diretorio proc?

Tags: linux

ERROR - Cannot stat file /proc/32641/fd/338 -

Qual utilidade do diretorio proc para o fuser ?

Existe esta explicação em algum manual do linux ?

ou em inglês

ERROR - Can not stat file / proc / 32641 / fd / 338 -

What is the usefulness of the proc directory for the fuser?

Is there an explanation in some linux manual?

Answer (score 1):

O diretório `/proc` contem algumas estatísticas sobre a máquina. No geral, são arquivos crus sem formatação. Por exemplo:

```
[leandro@localhost ~]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 30
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         870  @ 2.93GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x7
cpu MHz     : 1200.000
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
...
```

Você tem dados sobre memória, processos, tráfego de rede, discos. O utilitário `top`, por exemplo, utiliza esses arquivos.
Usualmente o linux monta esse *filesystem* no *startup*.

No seu caso,

```
/proc/32641/fd/338
```

significa 32641 é o número do processo e 338 é o *file descriptor* utilizado pelo processo. Possivelmente dentro deste diretório, teria estatísticas da utilização dele. Mas, como o processo talvez tivesse terminado, mostrou a mensagem de erro ao listar, porque não existia.

Referência para leitura [/proc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) do manual do kernel.

Answer (score 1):

> O **/proc** no Linux é um diretório virtual que serve como "diagnóstico" e configurações em tempo real do kernel.

O sistema de arquivos **/proc** é um diretório especial onde fica todas as informações de depuração do kernel. Também se encontram algumas configurações que habilitam e desabilitam o suporte à alguma coisa no kernel. É muito útil para o diagnóstico do seu hardware. Vou aqui comentar arquivos do **/proc** para você 'depurar' o seu hardware:

```
/proc/devices
```

Aqui estão os dispositivos encontrados no seu sistema, incluindo modem, placa de som, placa de rede, teclado, impressora, etc.

```
/proc/interrupts
```

Neste arquivo estão as informações das IRQs dos dispositivos.

```
/proc/ioports
```

Informações sobre os endereços das portas I/O (Input/Output).

```
/proc/pci
```

Dispositivos PCI instalados no sistema. O comando 'lspci' também serve para mostrar esse arquivo.

```
/proc/cpuinfo
```

Aqui você pode ver as características do seu processador e máquina.

```
/proc/filesystems
```

Sistemas de arquivos suportados pelo kernel.

```
/proc/devices
```

Dispositivos gerais instalados.

```
/proc/meminfo
```

Informações da memória usada. O comando 'free' também serve para mostrar este arquivo.

```
/proc/modules
```

Módulos carregados no kernel. O comando 'lsmod' também serve para mostrar este arquivo.

```
/proc/mounts
```

Partições montadas. O comando 'mount' sem parâmetro nenhum mostra esse arquivo.

```
/proc/partitions
```

Partições existentes e que o Linux reconheceu.

```
/proc/version
```

Versão do kernel. O comando 'uname' também serve para mostrar este arquivo.

> Explore este diretório! Só não dê um cat no arquivo **/proc/kcore**, por favor! :) kcore = kernel core.